# parseInt fixing the value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I have a value with commas.

Ex:-`var abc = "10,10.12";`

If I use `var x = parseInt(abc);`

it is returning `10`

Expected output is `10,10.12`

as I have used `ng-value="UpdatedPropuesta.VALOR_CUOTA | number:2"`  in JSP.

Comment: The second argument to `parseInt` is the radix, not another number to parse. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt. Also if that's actually a *string* `'10,10.12'` then you need to `.split` it.

Comment: is its a string then what exactly do you want? input and output seem same to me.

Comment: please review your expected value. why should it be a valid integer in JS?

Comment: @SatishKumar the expected output in number format

Comment: Would it be an array of numbers then?

Comment: `"10,10.12"` -> `10,10.12`, `10,10.12` is not even a valid number, and also you want your input will be the same as your output? seriously?

Comment: @AmayaSan yes I need the same

Comment: oh okay, good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of numbers out of the string then try this,

```js
const input = "10,10.12";
var output = input.split(",");
output = output.map(i => Number(i));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>  10,10.12
> ```

That is not the number `1010.12`, it is the number `10`, a comma operator, and the number `10.12`.

Commas are not part of the JavaScript literal syntax.

However, in your case you're passing two arguments to `parseInt`, the first should be a string to convert (but JS will convert it to a strign) and the second is the radix – the number base – which should be an integer.

So JS's type conversion will lead to:

```
var x = parseInt('10', 10);
```

Which is of course 10.

**After question update**

> ```
> var x = parseInt("10,10.12");
> ```

As comma are not part of JS numeric literals, the parse will stop at the comma because it is not a character that can appear in a number.

So the answer is still 10.

Comment: actually it is a string.. String I need to convert into number

Comment: @NareshDonthula what you're showing in your question is *not* a string, it's two separate numerical arguments.

Comment: And I have edited the question (having also been reminded that `parseInt` can take two arguments)