# split a string with 2 decimals after dot

Tags: javascript

I have the following string.

```
var string = '14,12.1545';
```

In the above variable I need to take two decimals after dot. How to split the variable with dot.

the expected output is `14,12.15`

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: why split? and why teh a string as result?

Comment: it looks a bit similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074298/parseint-fixing-the-value

Comment: @NinaScholz Finally I want to take only two decimals after dot. that's why I thought split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a pure string manipulation point of view: separate the string into two parts, one before the dot and one after. Use `slice` to select only the first two characters of the after-string, and then put them back together.

```js
function translateString(input) {
  const [beforeDot, afterDot] = input.split('.');
  const afterDotTrimmed = afterDot.slice(0, 2);
  return beforeDot + '.' + afterDotTrimmed;
}
console.log(translateString('14,12.1545'));
console.log(translateString('14,12.1'));
console.log(translateString('14,12.154534534534'));
```

You could also use a regular expression:

```js
function translateString(input) {
  return input.replace(/\.(\d{1,2}).*$/, '.$1');
}
console.log(translateString('14,12.1545'));
console.log(translateString('14,12.1'));
console.log(translateString('14,12.154534534534'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to array and make the changes

```js
let str='14,12.1123,3.1415926554';
let arr=str.split(",");
let n=arr.map(a=>a.indexOf('.') !== -1 ? parseFloat(a).toFixed(2) : parseFloat(a));
console.log(n.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can borrow a suitable number formatter from previous answers, like this:
[How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)

Then you can change your text to a number and format it. I assume that you want round from half up, like this:

```js
// suitable answer from question 149055
Number.prototype.format = function(n, x) {
    var re = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + (x || 3) + '})+' + (n > 0 ? '\\.' : '$') + ')';
    return this.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~n)).replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), '$&,');
};

var string = '14,12.1545'
var number = parseFloat(string.replace(/,/g , ""))
console.log(number.format(2, 2)) // -> 14,12.15

string = '99,99.9999'
number = parseFloat(string.replace(/,/g , ""))
console.log(number.format(2, 2)) // -> 1,00,00.00
```